# Accessing all elements of a GridEditableItem in RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am intercepting the update operation for a RadGrid. like this

```
e.Canceled = true;
GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
Hashtable dictionary = new Hashtable();
item.ExtractValues(dictionary);
```

This gives me the changed values in the HashTable. The problem is I want to access ALL the elements of the current row. How do i do that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you replace

> `item.ExtractValues(dictionary);`

with

```
e.Item.OwnerTableView.ExtractValuesFromItem(dictionary,item);
```

you should have all the elements in the dictionary.